# Unexpected value 'QRCodeModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular, ionic2, qr-code

I am trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-qrcode in my ionic application.
It is an ionic2 App using ionic angular 2.0.0-rc.0

When I am doing ionic serve everything works perfectly
However when I do an ionic run I am getting

```
[19:05:49]  ngc: Error: Unexpected value 'QRCodeModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'
at D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13982:37
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:13967:46)
at D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12812:58
at Array.forEach (native)
at OfflineCompiler.analyzeModules (D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:12811:21)
at CodeGenerator.codegen (D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\codegen.js:105:47)
at codegen (D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:7:81)
at Object.main (D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:30:16)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\jdevcc\git\pr\application\handyou-original\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\main.js:14:9)
```

Do you maybe have an idea?

Is there a way to have the full log for ngc compilation? In order to check if something wrong happened before.

Here is my app module:

```
...
...

  imports: [QRCodeModule, SwingModule
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
  tabsHideOnSubPages : 'true'
})
```

],

For information the swing module is working perfectly :) In my package.json I have "angular2-qrcode": "^1.0.4",

Thanks in advance for your ideas

Have a nice day :)

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I will put the explenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally to have it working but it is a bit crappy.

had to copy paste the angular2-qrcode.ts in my local repository ( I took it from https://github.com/SuperiorJT/angular2-qrcode/pull/4)

Once it has been done I had to modify the import

replace:

```
import * as qrcode from "qrcode-generator";
```

by:

```
import qrcode from "qrcode-generator";
```

Then I installed qrcode-generator (npm install qrcode-generator --save)

I know that this is not the best solution but they have to produce *metadata.json and it has not been done currently...

In addition it is MIT License so we can coppy it and modify it as we want :)

Good luck and don't hesitate to put a up